# Usuário com própria página

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, banco-de-dados, api

Eu to fazendo um portal, e para fazer o cadastro precisa de cpf e email. Aí envio um email de confirmação, ele clica no link e a situação dele no meu bd muda. Assim o usuario pode acessar o portal. Só vai ter uma página, e todos os usuários irão usar a mesma página, só que os dados que virão da api serão diferentes de cada um. Como faço pra saber que o usuário que entrou (preciso saber a partir do cpf) é tal pessoa para colocar os dados, e tal.

Página `index.php`

```
<?php session_start(); include 'config/conexao.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- As 3 meta tags acima *devem* vir em primeiro lugar dentro do `head`; qualquer outro conteúdo deve vir *após* essas tags -->
    <title>Lojas Guido | Portal do Cliente - Login</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/icon/guido.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script>
             $(function(){
                       $("#footer").load("footer.php");
              });
        </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top fot" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">

          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#elementoCollapse1">

              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>

          </button>

          <a href="http://lojasguido.com.br/" target="_blank" class="navbar-brand links nome">Lojas Guido</a>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/lojasguido/" target="_blank" class="navbar-brand links nome"></span><span class="fa fa-facebook-square" style="font-size:24px"></span></a>
          <a href="https://www.google.com.br/search?q=lojas+guido&npsic=0&rflfq=1&rlha=0&rllag=-9663965,-35738591,201&tbm=lcl&ved=0ahUKEwi4-pKZsoLYAhXJkOAKHexfD34QtgMIKw&tbs=lrf:!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e3!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:10&rldoc=1#rlfi=hd:;si:;mv:!1m3!1d9280.090187594818!2d-35.724626199999996!3d-9.6568108!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i791!2i453!4f13.1;tbs:lrf:!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e3!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:10" target="_blank" class="navbar-brand links nome"></span><span class="fa fa-map-marker" style="font-size:24px"></span></a>

        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="elementoCollapse1">

          <div class="navbar-form navbar-right">

                <a class="btn btn-default" href="cadastro.php" role="button">Cadastrar</a>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </nav>


    </div>


        <div class="container">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="col-xs-12 ok">
                  <h1 class="portal">Portal do Cliente</h1>

                    <div class="form-login">
                        <h2>Entrar</h2>

                        <form name="formulario" id="formEnvia"  method="POST">

                          <?php
                            include "config/valida.php";
                           ?>

                            <label >CPF*</label>
                            <span>Apenas números</span>

                            <input type="text" id="cpf" name="cpf" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="000.000.000-00" maxlength="14"
      title="Digite apenas números" required />
                    <br>
                            <label inputemail>E-mail*:</label>
                            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control input-lg " placeholder="SeuEmail@Email.com" maxlength="50" required/>

                            <br>
                            <button type="submit" name="valida" id="valida" value="valida" onclick="valida_envio()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                              <span id="cpf"></span>Acessar</button>
                                <br>
                                <span>Não possui cadastro?</span>  <a class="btn btn-default bot" href="cadastro.php" role="button">Cadastre-se</a>

                        </form>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<br>
<br><br>

<!-- RODAPÉ -->

<div id="footer"></div>

<!-- FIM RODAPÉ -->




<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script src="js/ValidaCpf.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Página `valida.php`

```
<?php


require_once "config/conexao.php";

if(isset($_REQUEST['valida'])){
  $var1 = $_REQUEST['cpf'];
  $var2 = $_REQUEST['email'];
$query = "SELECT `leados`.`email`, `leados`.`cpf`, `links_emaos`.`situacao` from `leados` INNER JOIN `links_emaos` ON `leados`.`id` = `links_emaos`.`leado_id` WHERE situacao = '2' AND cpf='$var1' AND email= '$var2'";




         $querySelect = mysqli_query($conn,$query);


         if ($received_token === token()) {


         if(mysqli_num_rows($querySelect) == 0){
           $mensagem = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>CPF ou E-mail incorreto!</div>";
           printf ($mensagem);
         }else {

           $_SESSION['cpf'] = $var1;
           $_SESSION['email'] = $var2;
         header("Location:postagem.php");
       }
}else {
  $mensagem = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Você não tem autorização para entrar!</div>";
  printf ($mensagem);
}
}
```

***Obs.: apaguei os códigos do token***

Comment: pelo que me parece você está salvando o cpf e email dele em uma session, você não consegue usar esse valor para indicar à sua api qual é o usuário logado?

Comment: Eu fiz nas 3 páginas que existe do site (já depois de logado)
<body onLoad="load();">
    <?php

          $secao_cpf = $_SESSION['cpf'];
          $secao_email   = $_SESSION['email'];

         ?>
Mas não sei se isso já faz o api saber o cpf logado

Answer (score 0):

Passe os dados do usuário presentes na variável `SESSION` para a página de *dashboard* do usuário, dentro da página do *dashboard*, você pode validar os dados efetuando uma nova consulta no banco de dados com os valores capturados na variável de sessão.

Comment: Não tenho essa página dashboard

Comment: dashboard é a página inicial que o usuário vai acessar ao entrar no sistema. É para essa página que você precisará enviar os dados via `SESSION`